# Where are we now?

Tags: discussion

I haven't seen anything on the overall health of econ.se for a while.

- How is econ.se doing relative to other beta stack exchanges?
- Is usage growing, has it plateaued, or is it declining?
- Is *quality* improving?
- Are we likely to get out of beta? If so, when? Is there still a threat of closure?

Comment: If I remember the previous values correctly, over the past couple of months it seems that on many counts in area51 the criteria have worsened. In particular, the percentage of questions answered has declined from the mid 80s to 78. I think previously were "green" on many counts where we are now "orange".

Answer (score 7):

Here is the Area 51 snapshot:
[image]
[Source](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61732?phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top) on 2/26/16

[Compared with four months ago](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/prolonged-trends-of-the-beta-adjustments?rq=1) it looks like we doing better on some attributes and worse on others:

1. 0.8 questions fewer per day
2. 3 percentage points lower answer rate
3. 22 percent more avid users and 48 percent more total users
4. Unchanged answer ratio
5. 11 percent more daily visits.

Since the answer ratio isn't changing I'm not sure what is causing the decline in answered questions. Perhaps other stack exchanges have strategies for getting people to accept answers. I've been told that some SE sites, like the Math one, have lots of unanswered questions and people are fine with in that community.

Comment: If the answer ratio isn't changing, but the percentage that are answered is decreasing, then the answers are being more focused on specific questions. That is, when people choose to answer questions, they are slightly more likely compared with four months ago to answer questions that have been answered before.

I use math.SE a lot, and we have hardly any unanswered questions. When a question is poor, it is either downvoted and commented on, which prompts the OP to improve it, or it is closed. Closing or deleting bad questions cleans up the site.

Answer (score 4):

Looking in the moderator's analytics control panel, it looks as though site activity (visits, posts, etc.) increased to a peak during mid-summer 2015 before dropping back a bit over the last few months. I think this is more the product of seasonality than an actual negative trend in activity. Currently, activity looks *slightly* higher than the levels we were seeing this time last year.